# Ionic 3 getCurrentPosition always timeout on Nexus 5

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 3 and all the plugins are up to date.
There is an "ionic cordova plugin ls"

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.6.5 "Diagnostic"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

When i try to obtain the current position and log it to the console with

```
this.geo.getCurrentPosition(options).then((resp) => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
})
```

I always obtain an PositionError code 3 "Timeout expired" on my Nexus 5
(everything works fine in the browser).

I'm struggling with that for days and I've tried all the possible combinations of GeolocalOptions and (hw) position accuracy, I've tried to reboot my device several times and my android manifest permissions are right.
I've also tried to remove/reinstall the plugins and to remove/add "android platform" to cordova, nothing works.

Comment: I'm with the same problem